# Помощь в разработке игры на Java & LWJGL

Tags: java, разработка-игр, lwjgl

В общем, я новичок и хочу разработать собственную небольшую игру на Java & LWJGL, по типу Stardew Valley. Она будет в плане графики простенькой: пиксельная, tile-based, 2D, видом сверху. Нужна помощь по тому, как эффективно рендерить текстуры, тайлы, и в целом левела, как сделать простенькое освещение, по типу той же Stardew Valley и другие элементы игры. Хотелось бы услышать либо совет как это всё сделать, либо, желательно, я мог бы с вами как-нибудь связаться, и, если у вас есть опыт в программировании игр, то вы бы мне помогли более-детально: просматривали код игры, давали какие-то советы и прочее. В общем, ищу некого наставника.

Comment: хмм.. ты точно не хочешь выбрать себе какой-нибуть движок? lwjgl - не простая библиотека, и для новичка может стать препятствием при написании первой игры..